# apicontroller facade for wcf

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a wcf project running on IIS in a server that is not reachable from clients on the internet.
second project is the website that is open to the internet written in MVC c#4 razor engine.
I work a lot on just passing data from api controller to service client and back .
Is there a way to generate the code ?

let's say the code in my wcf service is on server unreachable to Internet is :

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IAlertsService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void ApproveAlert(int ID);
        [OperationContract]
        bool IsAdditionalPackageRequired(int AlertID);
        [OperationContract]
        bool RemoveAlert(int ID);
        //ApproveAllAlerts
        [OperationContract]
        bool ApproveAllAlerts(int[] ID);
    }
```

and I did service reference from website mvc4, and want to make controller api :

```
public class AlertsController : ApiController
{
   //here all methods to invoke wcf ...
}
```

is there a way to generate ApiControllers code from the service reference ?